# Ensuring onMessageReceived() is invoked when a FCM data message is sent even when App is closed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, pyfcm

I am trying to send FCM **data messages** from my server. This is how a message request looks like:

```
POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{ "data": {
    "score": "5x1",
    "time": "15:10"
  },
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1..."
}
```

or, when I use `PyFcm`:

```
push_service = FCMNotification(api_key=MY_API_KEY)
data_payload = {"score": "5x1", "time": "15:10"}
push_service.notify_single_device(registration_id="bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...", data_message=data_payload)
```

I made sure it is a data message by leaving out the `notification` part. In this way, according to the [FCM guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive), `onMessageReceived()` of a `FirebaseMessagingService` will be invoked when an app is **in the background or the foreground**.

However when the app **is closed**, sometimes `onMessageReceived()` is invoked, and sometimes it is not. Is there any way for me to make sure it is **always** invoked, even when the app is closed?

Comment: Can you share your `onMessageReceived()` code?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39505298/4625829).

Comment: @AbdulKawee In my onMessageReceived(), I just wrote a log and wrote something to the SharedPreferences.

Comment: Lots of good info in @AL's answer regarding [Stopped State](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44053217/4815718).  When you "close" the app, are you doing it in a way and on a device that might put the app into Stopped State?

Comment: @BobSnyder By closing, I mean I just swipe it horizontally away in the task view. Does it matter?

Comment: On some phones, swiping from the task view ("recents") puts the app in Stopped state and it will not receive FCM messages until the user opens it.

Comment: @BobSnyder So this "stopped state" is different from the `onStop()` being called when an app moves out of the foreground?

Comment: Yes, in this context stopped state means more than just being in the background with onStopped() called.