# Firebase onMessageReceived() not called via pyfcm

Tags: android, firebase, pyfcm

I am trying to pass "badge" numbers via FCM.
I know that onMessageReceived() only get called when :
[payload contains only "data", no message]

I am using "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2"
 and **pyfcm** on server side to send my notification by this.

```
result = push_service.notify_multiple_devices(
    registration_ids=ids, data_message={'badge': '5'}
)
>> all success.
```

My Service :

```
public class MyFCMService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
  private static final String TAG = "MyFCMService";
  public MyFCMService() {
  }

  @Override
  public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.d(TAG, remoteMessage.getData().toString());
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
  }
}
```

My Service in manifest.xml:

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<service
    android:name=".MyFCMService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44193726/ensuring-onmessagereceived-is-invoked-when-a-fcm-data-message-is-sent-even-whe) but I didn't close the app (just press HOME)
but still, logcat(verbose) shows nothing.
Is there any possible reasons?

Comment: you should first confirm your Android code first by using FCM console. if it is working fine after then you may check your backend.

Comment: I can get those message from FCM composer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason while copying my code in Manifest file...

it should be

```
<application>
    ...
    <service
        android:name=".libs.fcm.MyFCMService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

NOT

```
<service
    android:name=".libs.fcm.MyFCMService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<application>
    ...
</application>
```

result:

```
D/MyFCMService: {badge=5}
```

and badge number can be update by ShortcutBadger through notification 
with a datapayload contains badge.

```
pyfcm:
result = push_service.notify_multiple_devices(registration_ids=registration_ids, data_message=data_message, click_action=click_action, message_title=message_title,message_body=message_body, message_icon=message_icon)


Android Service
@Override
public void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if(intent.hasExtra("badge"))
}
```